# Port Number 8080 required for GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

Is it necessary to use the port number such as **8080** for GeoServer i.e. will it not work with a different port number?

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to use port number 8080 for GeoServer, typically that is the default one defined within the installer.